# Which's better for WINE?

Tags: 12.04, wine, games, 13.04, mta

I have a little question: Which version of Ubuntu works better with WINE? The actual version (13.04) or LTS? (12.04)

Because I'd like to play MTA San Andreas in Linux and the most of people says I can, but I don't know which version of Ubuntu works better with Wine.

Thats all, thanks.

Comment: The answer to this question may differ from user to user, but I noticed the switch to Raring fixed some bugs I had with running programs through wine on 12.10. I'd go for 13.04. Starcraft and starcraft brood war run fine. I'm installing Starcraft 2 and so far so good. Installed firefox with the newest version of flash (adobe stopped supporting linux with the newer versions of flash) and it runs well. But no one can answer your question, it's partly dependant on your hardware. Refer to wine's appdb to see how others fare with mta san andreas.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the version of wine is more important then the version of Ubuntu. It varies by software package, see winehq for details.

http://appdb.winehq.org/

If you look at a complex application, you will see it works better or worse with various versions of wine.

Example: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2586

Works for earlier versions of NET, not so good with most recent versions.

Because wine is sometimes difficult to configure, more and more people seem to prefer virtualization (virtualbox or KVM).

Comment: So wrong. The example doesn't show Wine versions, but .NET versions. Wine is not difficult to configure. Virtualization is very bad for games.

Comment: I have to disagree, wine is "simple" for simple applications, but configuration can be quite complex with games and can fail completely. It varies widely. Also take note that the wine data base lists version of wine used for testing.

Comment: Was going to answer with a good explanation but this answer is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried wine on 13.04 but in the past I've found the later versions of ubuntu have often yielded the best results. Whether because of newer kernels, wine versions or supporting software, generally in most cases the latest versions are a little faster and usually more stable.